# Can you define a Class (objc_class) parameter to have a required subclass at compile time?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following method:

```
- (FDModel *)_modelForClass: (Class)modelClass 
    withIdentifier: (NSString *)identifier
```

which should take in a Class and a identifier, create an instance of modelClass, assign the identifier and do some other work based on the fact that it assumed modelClass is a subclass of FDModel.

I can put in a check that raises some error or exception if `[modelClass isSubclassOfClass: [FDModel class]] == NO` but I was trying to see if there was a way to enforce this at compile time.

EDIT: I understand that some people see this as a obvious factory method but the modelClass parameter is actually passed in by the user of my library through a delegate callback `- (Class<FDModel>)modelClassForDictionary: (NSDictionary *)dictionary;`. This question was more aimed at making the user of my library return a Class that has a specific subclass.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider the plain answer to your question being no; there is no way of checking if a class passed as a parameter is of a certain kind.

But I'd like to argue that the essence of your question primarily points to a design issue, i.e. can't your instance-generating method be expressed as a factory method? Like so:

```
@interface FDModel

+ (instancetype)modelWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

@end
```

In the above case you would simply do:

```
[FDModel modelWithIdentifier:anIdentifier];
```

The actual class returned (and the initialisation logic) being specified by the factory method implementation through subclassing of the FDModel class:

```
@implementation FDModelSubclass

+ (instancetype)modelWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    FDModel *model = [super modelWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (model)
    {
        // do additional init stuff
    }
    return model;
}

@end
```

Nothing to check, no chance to go wrong.

Comment: the return type here should be `instancetype`, so that the compiler is aware that a subclass' factory method is generating an instance of the subclass, not strictly FDModel

Comment: I drastically simplified the description of the method. I keep a list of all FDModel objects ever instantiated through this method and ensure that only one FDModel object with the identifier ever exists. I can (and probably will) use the factory method if a model does not exist but the modelClass is actually provided to this method through a delegate. I ask the user of my data client what Class they would like to be instantiate for a given NSDictionary. This is the current delegate method `- (Class<FDModel>)modelClassForDictionary: (NSDictionary *)dictionary;` which will need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I don't think you can do it at compile time - you have to do it at runtime as you expected.

```
BOOL classConformsToProtocol = [class conformsToProtocol:@protocol(OKAProtocol)];
```

OR

```
BOOL classConformsToProtocol = [self class:[OKAClass class] conformsToProtocol:@"OKAProtocol"];

------

- (BOOL)class:(Class)class conformsToProtocol:(NSString *)protocol;
{
  return [class conformsToProtocol:NSProtocolFromString(protocol)];
}
```

Comment: That is actually what I originally did and it doesn't work like you think it does http://stackoverflow.com/a/21885046/1666298

Comment: I wrote that on my lunch break on my iPhone - should have looked into it, I have updated my answer